# Unable to Browse Global Navigation or use Manage Site Content and Structure

Tags: navigation, content-and-structure

Have a customer site which has gone through a migration, I noticed post migration its not possible to Browser Global Navigation or use the Manage Site Content and Structure. I've got a dump of the logs with the correlation ID, appears to be an issue where a site is not closed properly or something along those lines> these 2 things appear to be related but not sure how to track down whats causing it. This is the dump from the ULS logs when triggering the 'browse site' function when editing navigation structure.

```
06/29/2012 17:49:22.08  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://portal:80/academic/eLearningV2/_layouts/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx?&AssetUrl=/academic/eLearningV2/&RootFolder=/academic/eLearningV2/&MDWeb=a23259f4-236e-4a22-a2f5-58e469d68e79&AssetType=Link)  a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.08  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.11  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   General 90hv    Unexpected  Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.  Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPHierarchyDataView.Select()     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataHierarchyDataView.GetUnderlyingViewData()     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataHierarchyDataView.GetReorderedWebChildNodes()     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataHierarchyDataView.GetHierarchyNodesForView()     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataHierarchyDataView.Select()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindNode(TreeNode node)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.PerformDataBinding()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPTreeView.PerformDataBinding()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPTreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP._layouts_assetportalbrowser_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.12  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (SPTreeView: {Root of tree}). Execution Time=15.4994559364388   a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.15  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  Document Management Server  Document Management eua9    Medium  Pending update MetadataNavigationHints for Web[4e677ce9-079b-4a77-9ef3-ddf4dccd77b9]List[4d4fbb3b-1f68-46dc-a8f8-4ae3a4393a8d] = 0 (NoSettings) a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.17  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   General 72k8    High    Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature {49C93666-8ACF-49BC-9FE1-4083ABB0E238}, list template 101.    a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.17  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentException: Feature '49c93666-8acf-49bc-9fe1-4083abb0e238' for list template '101' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could not be completed.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c__DisplayClass19.<GetFeatureRootAndListSchemaPaths>b__18()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken, Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.GetFeatureRootAndListSchemaPaths(Byte[]& userToken, Guid& tranLockerId, Int32 nZone, Guid databaseid, Guid siteid, Guid webid, Guid featid, Int32 ltid, String& sPathToFeatureRoot, String& sPathToSchemaXml)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetViewsSchemaXml(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bFullBlown, Boolean bNeedInitAllViews, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plDefaultViewIndex, Int32& plMobileDefaultViewIndex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetViewsSchemaXml(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bFullBlown, Boolean bNeedInitAllViews, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plDefaultViewIndex, Int32& plMobileDefaultViewIndex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.EnsureViewSchema(Boolean fullBlownSchema, Boolean bNeedInitallViews)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.get_Views()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedList.GetMetadataNavSettingsXmlNoCache(SPList sourceList)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavSettingsXmlNoCache(SPList sourceList)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavSettingsXml(SPWeb web, Guid sourceListId, Boolean& listExists)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavigationSettings(SPWeb web, Guid sourceListId, Boolean checkWebPropHint)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.GetMetadataNavigationHintsForList(SPWeb web, Guid listGuid)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataHierarchyNodeSiteObject.get_HasChildren()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindRecursive(TreeNode node, IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable, Boolean ignorePopulateOnDemand)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.PerformDataBinding()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPTreeView.PerformDataBinding()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPTreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.17  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    High    An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {A71A4471-295E-4F1F-8D72-4B1AE91B5F81}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.   a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
06/29/2012 17:49:22.17  w3wp.exe (0x1840)   0x16B4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://portal:80/academic/eLearningV2/_layouts/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx?&AssetUrl=/academic/eLearningV2/&RootFolder=/academic/eLearningV2/&MDWeb=a23259f4-236e-4a22-a2f5-58e469d68e79&AssetType=Link)). Execution Time=95.9538153592146    a066bc12-8a26-4a85-a549-413e11fde76c
```

Main thing I'm looking at is Feature 'GUID' is not installed on the site template 101?

Maybe an stsadm enumallwebs might shed some light?

I found [this post](http://sharepointyankee.com/2011/08/18/generic-errors-with-lists-and-manage-content-and-structure-tool/) which is exactly what I need to do with these features being lost in the process. The thing is I can't actually figure out what the offending list is, can anyone point out how to track down the offending list given the ULS logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you upgraded? A new server with a DB attach? It looks like you have features installed in your old farm which are not present in your new farm. You have a couple of choices here:-

1) Find the features in your old farm, disable/remove them if possible, do the DB attach again with a fresh copy of the DB.

2) Find the missing features and bring them across and install to the new farm, assuming they are compatible with 2010.

You might be able to get away with bringing the feature folders across manually if there is no WSP for them, installing them, this should make the errors go away so you can deactivate the features in the site. Then finally remove the manually added features.

Comment: It was probably the worst migration ever. Their existing WFE was corrupt, I had to build a new 2007 farm and attach the content DB to that, from there the inplace was attempted and failed, so I had to do the DB attach process, I came out of that relatively OK but have this particular issue, I will only really have the choice of doing a force uninstalll I believe, using the GUID from the ULS logs.

Comment: You might find though that you have lists that you can't easily get into as their underlying list definition will have disappeared. It's possible that you might be able to blow them away through powershell.

Comment: Fixed! Yes I was able to track down the offending list, turned out to be a document form library. Basically exported all the lists of the site to a csv file and searched based on the feature ID GUID to find a 'Newsletters' library that had this feature template present. Used this script http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/3385.aspx which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, Most likely there is a corrupt feature in your site collection, it normally happens when you delete a feature without deactivating it, but i dont know what happened in this case.

The best thing is to retract the feature solution from central admin, if you deployed it using wsp, otherwise you can use a STSADM command to un install the feature using Force, it did helped me many times.

> stsadm.exe -o uninstallfeature
>              {-filename  |
>               -name  |
>               -id }
>              [-force]

or check out this tool

Cheers

[Feature Admin](http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2008/04/28/stsadm-o-export-fatalerror-failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array.aspx)

Comment: Yeah well initially I thought that was the case, I have run FeatureAdmin over the site and it found 1 faulty feature (I do love that tool) but hasn't been able to fix this particular problem. I believe it might be a list, there is a GUID in that ULS dump, if I can track that down it could be whats causing it.